# If memory is already allocated, will changes made in the array inside a function be preserved in the main or calling functions?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, multidimensional-array, pass-by-reference

In this function definition, I have taken arguments for address of 2 D array.

```
void dynamic(int ***a,int r,int c)
{
    *a = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*r);
    for(int i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        (*a)[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*c);
    }

}
```

I am passing arguments as shown below,

```
dynamic(&a,r1,c1);
```

If I take 2d array as an argument directly, then it's not taking input.

But, In this code, in add function I am not taking address of a 2 D array, instead I am taking 2D array itself, but the changes made are being retained.

```
void add(int **a,int **b,int r,int c,int **sum)
{
      static int i=0,j=0;
      if(i>=r)
      {
          return;// sum;
      }
      else
      {
          if(j<c)
          {
              sum[i][j] = a[i][j]+b[i][j];
              j++;
              add(a,b,r,c,sum);
          }
          j=0;
          i++;
          add(a,b,r,c,sum);
      }
}
```

But If take reference for add function, I am getting garbage value.

```
void add(int **a,int **b,int r,int c,int ***sum)
{
      static int i=0,j=0;
      if(i>=r)
      {
          return;
      }
      else
      {
          if(j<c)
          {
              (*sum)[i][j] = a[i][j]+b[i][j];
              j++;
              add(a,b,r,c,sum);
          }
          j=0;
          i++;
          add(a,b,r,c,sum);
      }
}
```

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void input(int **a,int r,int c)
{
     for(int i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<c;j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
void dynamic(int ***a,int r,int c)
{
    *a = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*r);
    for(int i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        (*a)[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*c);
    }

}
int** matmul(int **a,int r1,int c1,int **b,int r2,int c2,int **c)
{
    static int i=0,j=0,k=0;
    if(i>r1)
    {
        return c;
    }
    else
    {

        if(j<c2)
        {
            if(k==0)
             {
                c[i][j]=0;
             }
            if(k<r2)
            {
                c[i][j]+= a[i][k]*a[k][j];
                k++;
                printf("product = %d ",c[i][j]);
                matmul(a,r1,c1,b,r2,c2,c);
            }
            k=0;
            j++;
            matmul(a,r1,c1,b,r2,c2,c);
        }
        j=0;
        i++;
        matmul(a,r1,c1,b,r2,c2,c);
    }
}
void freeing(int **arr,int r,int c)
{
    for(int i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        free(arr[i]);
    }
    free(arr);
}

void print_array(int **a,int r,int c)
{
    for(int i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<c;j++)
        {
            printf("%d ",a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return;
}

void main()
{
    int **a,**b,r1,c1,r2,c2,i,j,**product;
    printf("Enter the number of rows and columns in first matrix\n");
    scanf("%d%d",&r1,&c1);

    printf("Enter the number of rows and columns in first matrix\n");
    scanf("%d%d",&r2,&c2);
    if(r2==c1)
    {
        printf("Enter First array\n");
        dynamic(&a,r1,c1);
        input(a,r1,c1);


        printf("Enter Second array\n");
        dynamic(&b,r2,c2);
        input(b,r2,c2);

        printf("First matrix is\n");
        print_array(a,r1,c1);

        printf("Second matrix is\n");
        print_array(b,r2,c2);

        dynamic(&product,r1,c2);
        {
            if(product[0]==NULL)
            {
                printf("memory not allocated\n");
            }
        }
        product=matmul(a,r1,c1,b,r2,c2,product);
        printf("Product of 2 matrices are\n");
        print_array(product,r1,c2);

        freeing(a,r1,c1);
        freeing(b,r2,c2);
        freeing(product,r1,c2);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Array multiplication not possible! enter correct dimension");
    }

}
```

I tried to write the a function for dynamically allocating a 2 D array, but input values were not being taken, I passed the address of the 2d ARRAY into the dynamic function, this time it worked. I applied the same logic for add function, but I was not getting correct result, when I passed 2 D array directly it worked, what might be the reason. Also I want dimensions of the array to be user defined.

Comment: You pass a pointer to be able to access (or modify) what the pointer is pointing to.

Comment: By the way, why are you calling `add` recursively? What is your actual assignment or exercise? And remember, once you have changed your `static` local variables, they won't be "reset" or initialized again, you can only call `add` *once* in your program.

Comment: `"If I take 2d array as an argument directly, then it's not taking input." -->  post that code.

Comment: Perhaps the problem you're asking about is because an array of arrays is ***not*** the same as a pointer to a pointer? While arrays decays to a pointer to its first element, this decay only happen to the outer array in the case of nested arrays. So if you have e.g. `int a[5][10];`, then `a` will decay to `&a[0]` which have the type `int (*)[10]`. No further decay happens.

Comment: @Pranav Vasishta Provide a minimal complete program that reproduces the problem.

Comment: `"If I take 2d array as an argument directly, then it's not taking input." --> post that code. –  It's the same code, but taking sum instead of &sum for dynamic function.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference in the results of calling these two recursive functions.

However the functions have a serious drawback: they will not work if called more than one time because the value of the static variable `i` is not reset to `0` after calls of the functions.

Also there is no great sense to declare the parameter `sum` like

```
int **sum
```

because the function does not change the pointer itself used as an argument. It changes data pointed to by the pointer.

Using your approach the recursive function can be defined the following way shown in the demonstration program below. The function is called twice to be sure that after calling the function the first time its static variables are reset correctly and the function may be called a second time.

Within the program there are not used dynamically allocated arrays to simplify the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void add( int **a, int **b, unsigned int r, unsigned int c, int **sum )
{
    static unsigned int i = 0, j = 0;

    if (i < r && j != c)
    {
        sum[i][j] = a[i][j] + b[i][j];
        if (++j == c)
        {
            j = 0;
            ++i;
        }

        add( a, b, r, c, sum );
    }
    else
    {
        i = 0;
    }
}

int main( void )
{
    enum { r = 2, c = 3 };

    int a0[c] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    int a1[c] = { 4, 5, 6 };
    int * aa[r] = { a0, a1 };
    int ** a = aa;

    int b0[c] = { 10, 20, 30 };
    int b1[c] = { 40, 50, 60 };
    int * bb[r] = { b0, b1 };
    int ** b = bb;

    int s0[c];
    int s1[c];
    int * ss[r] = { s0, s1 };
    int ** sum = ss;

    add( a, b, r, c, sum );

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < c; j++)
        {
            printf( "%d ", sum[i][j] );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );

    for (unsigned int  j = 0; j < c; j++)
    {
        s0[j] = 0;
        s1[j] = 0;
    }

    add( a, b, r, c, sum );

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < c; j++)
        {
            printf( "%d ", sum[i][j] );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
}
```

The program output is

```
11 22 33
44 55 66

11 22 33
44 55 66
```

As it can be seen the function works correctly every time when it is called.

The parameter `r` and `c` of the function have the unsigned integer type `unsigned int` instead of `int` because there is no sense to declare them as having a signed integer type. Though in general instead of the type `unsigned int` it will be better to use type `size_t`.

Comment: @DavidRanieri I compiled the program as a C++ program.:) I have changed the declaration of r and c.

Comment: But I wanted the dimensions of the array to be user defined.

Comment: @PranavVasishta It is just a demonstration program. You can either use variable length arrays or dynamically allocate arrays. What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

At this point:

```
(*sum)[i][j] = a[i][j]+b[i][j];
```

the compiler doesn't know the dimension of the arrays because the function:

```
void add(int **a,int **b,int r,int c,int ***sum)
```

is not providing such information, in other words, a pointer to pointer and a 2D array are not of the same type and you cannot expect the compiler to deduce `int(*)[dim]` or `int [][dim]` from an `int **`

Since C99 you can use VLAs ([variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)) to solve this problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void add(int rows, int cols, int (*a)[cols], int (*b)[cols], int (*sum)[cols])
{
    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++)
        {
            sum[row][col] = a[row][col] + b[row][col];
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int rows = 2, cols = 3;
    int ( *a )[cols] = malloc(sizeof(int) * rows * cols);
    int ( *b )[cols] = malloc(sizeof(int) * rows * cols);
    int (*sum)[cols] = malloc(sizeof(int) * rows * cols);

    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++)
        {
            a[row][col] = rand() % 100;
            b[row][col] = rand() % 100;
        }
    }
    add(rows, cols, a, b, sum);
    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++)
        {
            printf("%d + %d = %d, ", a[row][col], b[row][col], sum[row][col]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    free(a);
    free(b);
    free(sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Notice that VLAs were made optional in C11

Comment: But I wanted the dimensions of the array to be user defined.

Comment: You can define them: `scanf("%d", &rows); scanf("%d", &cols);` and you are done.